# Must I move data dependency out of my Controllers (and into Factories)?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, zend-framework2, inversion-of-control

This question can be viewed through a prism of ZF2 + Doctrine + MVC programming practices, or it can be viewed through just an OOP perspective.

My concern is about Separation of Concerns, and on removing dependencies.

I am using code in my controllers that goes something like this:

```
class MyController
{ 
    private $em; //entityManager 

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->em = DoctrineConnector::getEntityManager();
    }

    function indexAction()
    {
        //Input
        $inputParameter = filter_input(...);

        //request for Data
        $queryBuilder = $this->em->createQuery(...)
                             ->setParameter('param', $inputParameter);
        $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
        //$services is the user-defined data type requested
        $services = $query->getResult();

        //use data to produce a view model
        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->setVariables(array('services' => $services));
        return $view;
    }
}
```

I am not entirely comfortable with the above and wanted a second opinion. For one, my `EntityManager` is *part of the class*, so my class is cognizant of the entity manager construct, when I think it should not be a part of the controller.  Do I perhaps use a `Factory` or `Builder` design pattern to help me create `MyController` class?

If I do, I can move my `em` (entityManager) construct into the Factory pattern and create and populate my `MyController` inside the Factory.  Then, the `MyController` can have a private variable `$services` instead.

i.e.

```
class MyController
{ 
    private $services;

    function setServices($services)
    {
        $this->services = $services;
    }

    function indexAction()
    {
        //use data to produce a view model
        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->setVariables(array('services' => $this->services));
        return $view;
    }
}

class MyFactoryMethod
{
    function createMyController()
    {
        //Input
        $inputParameter = filter_input(INPUT_GET...);

        //request for Data
        $queryBuilder = $this->em->createQuery(...)
                             ->setParameter('param', $inputParameter);
        $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
        //$services is the user-defined data type requested
        $services = $query->getResult();

        //create and return MyController instance
        $controller = new MyController();
        $controller->setServices($services);
        return $controller;
    }
}
```

I typically tried to do this PHP's `mysql` extension to remove dependency on data out of my various objects.  I am using Doctrine2 now which is an ORM, and wondering if I should keep doing the same thing (namely preferring 2nd example rather than the first...

**Question:**

I can write code both ways. It works essentially the same.  My question is -- is the code, as it is written in my 2nd example preferred more than the code as it is written in my first?

**Notes / Clarifications:**

In my case variable `$services` is a domain-specific variable (not ZF2's `ServiceLocator`).  i.e. think of `MyController` as a controller for business-specific "services".

I am not harnessing full power of ZF2 with configs, routers, events, and everything.  I am using ZF2 modules on an existing legacy codebase on as-needed basis.

Answer (score 2):

When your controller has hard dependencies I would suggest to use the common ZF2 solution by creating the controller and injecting the dependency in a factory instance and registering the controller under the `'factories'` key in your `'controllers'` config array.

**In your `module.config.php`**

```
'controllers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Application\Controller\MyController' => 'Application\Controller\MyControllerFactory'
    )
)
```

In your controller I would set hard dependency in the `__construct` method. Like this you prevent the controller from ever being instantiated without your dependencies (it will throw an exception).

Never inject something like `$services` (if this is a `ServiceLocator`) from which you will pull the actual dependencies since it is not clear what the class actually needs. It will be harder to understand for other developers and it is also hard to test since you cannot set mocks for your individual dependencies so easily.

**Your Controller class:**

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class MyController
{ 
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    function indexAction()
    {
        //Do stuff
        $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
    }

    /**
     * @return EntityManager
     */
    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->entityManager;
    }
}
```

**Your Factory:**

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class MyControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return MyController
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        /** @var EntityManager $entityManager */
        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()
        $entityManager = $serviceManager->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        $myController = new MyController($entityManager);
        return $myController;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case `$services` is part of "business logic" (not `ServiceLocator`) - sorry about that. Think of it as `$myCustomVar`. So you are saying that:
1) it is okay for `MyController` to be aware of `EntityManager`, where `EntityManager` can pull any data from any of the available entities even ones not related to `MyController`.
2) using your example, why not go a bit further and have `createService` method run the appropriate DQL queries to pull up `MyController`-specific data, which you can then use to populate `MyController` using setter methods?  No `EntityManager` injection is then needed.

Comment: @Dennis Then I would suggest to inject your `EntityRepository` instance. So in your factory you find the correct repository for the entity class you want to work with (`$entityManager->getRepository(Entity::class);`). Then you can pull the methods in the repository where you have your DQL queries. You can of course also wrap all in a custom service instance. For example a `MyEntityService` for the entity class that you are interested in inside `MyController`. In this service you have `create`, `delete`, `update` and other entity related logic that you need inside the controller...

Answer (score 0):

There are two different approaches to this problem that are provided by ZF2.

1. Use the `ServiceLocator` to retrieve the `EntityManager` via a Factory.

   In `Module.php`, add an anonymous function or Factory.

   ```
   public function getServiceConfig()
   {
       return [
           'factories' => [
               'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager' => function (ServiceManager $sm) {
                   $entityManager = $sm->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
                   return $entityManager;
               }
           ],
       ],
   }
   ```

   In your Controller

   ```
   $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
   ```
2. Create an `Initializer` and `AwareInterface` to inject the `EntityManger` into your controllers.

   The `AwareInterface` can be added to any class which is initialized by the `ServiceManager`.

   ```
   interface EntityManagerAwareInterface
   {
       /**
        * Set EntityManager locator
        *
        * @param EntityManager $entityManager
        */
        public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $entityManager);

        /**
         * Get service locator
         *
         * @return EntityManager
         */
        public function getServiceLocator();
    }
   ```

   The `Initializer` is run when services are initialized by the `ServiceManager`.  A check is performed to so if `$instance` is a `EntityManagerAwareInterface`.

   ```
   use Application\EntityManager\EntityManagerAwareInterface;
   use Zend\ServiceManager\InitializerInterface;
   use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

   class EntityManagerInitializer implements InitializerInterface
   {
       /**
        * Initialize
        *
        * @param $instance
        * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
        * @return mixed
        */
       public function initialize($instance, ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
       {
           if ($instance instanceof EntityManagerAwareInterface) {            
               $entityManager = $serviceLocator->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
               $instance->setEntityManager($entityManager);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Next add the `Initializer` to `Module.php`

   ```
   public function getServiceConfig()
   {
       return [
           'initializers' => [
               'entityManager' => new EntityManagerInitializer(),
           ],
       ],
   }
   ```

The advantage of going the `Initializer` route is there is a one time setup.  Any class that implements the `EntityManagerAwareInterface` will have the `EntityManager` injected when the class is initialized.

Comment: The `initializer` example is a nice addition, but be aware that this method `initialize` in your `EntityManagerInitializer` will be called for every service instance that you get from your `ServiceLocator`. In large applications this can be a lot of times. A factory is only called once for only that specific service so there will be less overhead. The service can in such architecture (with initializers) also be instantiated without the (hard) dependency, this is in most cases undesirable.

Comment: @Wilt you are not wrong.  The `initializer` approach may not be efficient in some applications.  If the `EntityManager` is only used in a Controller, this approach would probably be overkill.  But, if you need the `EntityManager` to be accessible from other parts of your application, the additional overhead can be worth it.

Comment: well I like the answer(s) to the question, but ... they advocate one way or another to keep the `EntityManager` or its more restricted form inside the Controller (via various forms of injection).  They do not address the *why* it is the way to go.  Hence I pose the question "why".  I see `EntityManager` as the "data dependency" and I see that construct (EntityManager) staying firmly inside the Controller and not moving elsewhere.  Why is it inside the Controller?

Comment: @Dennis If it is a hard dependency it should be in the `__construct` method of the class. In this case the controller. References with details can be found easily; read for example the blog post [here](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2013/01/21/some-tips-to-write-better-zend-framework-2-modules/) for more details (especially the chapter *Set your hard dependencies in constructor, avoid initializers and setters/getters*). This is not only good practice in ZF2 applications but is a general rule for PHP classes.

Comment: to clarify -- .. I see code that utilizes `EntityManager` instances *inside* `MyController`.  Why not move that part out into i.e. Factory/elsewhere?  My concern is that there is a 'code construct' (aka data/aka EntityManager) that is somehow relied upon inside an `_Action()` method of a Controller and can run free-form queries.  An alternative way as I've suggested could be in my "block 2" code, where Controller is specifically populated by exactly the data it needs by outside forces and is itself does not contain any mention to or reference of an `EntityManager` or a similar data construct.

Comment: Check also the **Constructor Injection** chapter in [this article](http://coderoncode.com/dependency-injection/design-patterns/programming/php/development/2014/01/06/dependency-injection-php.html)

Comment: @Dennis if you are afraid of this, wrap it in another custom service that only allows access to a few public methods that you need access to. Or inject your repository so you can connect to your queries from there. Check also the comment under my answer.

Comment: @Dennis, your last comment is also a good practice.  Personally I choose not to interact directly with the `EntityManager` in Controllers.  I write Models that with methods that perform a specific action and the Models alone interact with the `EntityManager`.  This helps to abstract some of the code and make it more reusable.  This is one of the reasons that I enjoy developing with ZF2, it provides flexibility.

Comment: @atodd, thanks.  Can you give me an example of the model?  .. There are several ways where it can go so I am not sure I have the right idea in mind ..

Comment: @Dennis, Hight level overview here: I have an `AbstractModel` that has methods to retrieve the `EntityManager` and some basic find and findBy methods.  I then have a Model that extends the `AbstractModel`.  Each Model corresponds to a Doctrine Entity.  This allows the find and findBy methods to know which Entity to query.

Comment: Thanks.  My interest is in how you call this model.  Do you use a `ServiceLocator`?  Or do you inject it somehow into your controller. In essence, it seems to me that you are advocating data *staying* inside the Controller... ServiceLocator makes it a bit less painful of a dependency, but essentially, if it is anything like here:  http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html, then the entity that "does the data access" is planted firmly inside the controller and is "not moved out" as per my Question's title. In other words, the answer to my question is "NO".